# How can I output only the value of a registry key in a Batch File?

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, registry

Is it possible to get only the value of a registry key? (Windows 10)

When I run `reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper` in a batch file

I get the output      `Wallpaper    REG_SZ    c:\windows\web\wallpaper\windows\img0.jpg`

Is it possible to make the file only output `c:\windows\web\wallpaper\windows\img0.jpg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific task, you simply need to isolate part of the returned strings.

You can do that from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) using a `For` loop; like this:

```bash
@For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query
 "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V Wallpaper 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %%H
```

To learn how to use a `for` loop, open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

---

If you intend to further use that string, you may be better advised to save it as a variable instead:

```bash
@For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query
 "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /V Wallpaper 2^>NUL') Do @Set "img=%%~H"
```

You can then use `%img%` or `"%img%"` as necessary, elsewhere in your script, in place of the returned value string.

To learn how to use the `set` command, open a Command Prompt window, type `set /?`, and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.